# Encrypt RAM memory in Raspberry Pi

Tags: encryption, raspberry-pi, ram

I am supposed to demonstrate a scenario with and without encrypting RAM memory in Raspberry Pi. First of all, I want to know whether it is possible to encrypt RAM in Raspberry Pi. I tried googling about this but this topic seems to vague and ends up about Disk encryption.

Can someone give me any pointers about this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is not possible without hardware specifically designed for this. You can store some of your data encrypted in RAM. It all depends on what you want to achieve?

Comment: I am using Rpi 3. How do i encrpyt the ram in the first place? Is there any tools for it.

Comment: As I said: **It is not possible without hardware specifically designed for this.** This is not specific to Rpi3, this is true for all computer hardware. Are you sure you want to encrypt RAM?

Comment: Yes. I have to.

Comment: @InfamousCoder  And - what do you want to achieve? You can encrypt part of data, decrypt only when used and clean after using. And - you still need to have you decryption key somewhere. So - when you want some complete protection, it's not what Raspeberry (any comon HW) is built for